# sqlite3 doesn't write web content on my table

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I used the following command in order to create my own database:

```
sqlite3 mydb.db
```

I used the follwing command for making my table:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (hostName CHAR(50) PRIMARY KEY, content TEXT);
```

And this is part of my script:

```
hostName='mywebsite.com'
cur=con.cursor()
cur.execute('SELECT hostName FROM mytable WHERE hostName="'+hostName+'"')
data=cur.fetchall()
cont=session.get('http://'+hostName).content
cur.execute('INSERT INTO mytable (hostName,content) VALUES (\''+hostName+'\',\''+str(cont)+'\')')
```

But when I get the website content it doesn't write to the table when the content is not short.

Maybe there is a parameter larger than `TEXT`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Never** format contents of a column directly into a SQL-statement. Use placeholders instead:

```
cur.execute("SELECT hostName FROM mytable WHERE hostName=?", [hostName])
data = cur.fetchall()
cont = session.get('http://%s' % hostName).content
cur.execute("INSERT INTO mytable (hostName,content) VALUES (?,?)", [hostName, cont])
```